# Suppose that $\int_a^b [f'(x)^2]\int_a^b x^2f^2(x)>\dfrac{1}{4}.$

Tags: integration

Let $f$ a real function, continuously differentiable in $[a,b]$ such that $f(a)=f(b)=0$, and $$\int_a^bf^2(x)\ \text{d}x=1.$$ Prove that $$\int_a^b [f'(x)^2]\int_a^b x^2f^2(x)>\dfrac{1}{4}.$$

**My try.**

I previously proved that $$\int_a^b xf(x)f'(x)\ \text{d}x=-1/2.$$ By integration by parts.

The idea you have for this is to notice the following, $$\int_a^b [f'(x)^2]\int_a^b x^2f^2(x)\geq \int_a^b x^2f^2(x)[f'(x)]^2\ \text{d}x$$

And somehow with the integral that I tried previously to solve that last one, but I don't have much idea how to solve that one.

Answer (score 3):

The correct inequality is
$$\int_a^b [f'(x)^2]\int_a^b x^2f^2(x)\geq \left(\int_a^b xf(x)f'(x)\ \text{d}x)\right)^2$$
so you have proved the inequality.

The only thing we need to check is that we don't have the equality, since the equality holds if and only if $xf(x)=\alpha f'(x)$ for some $\alpha$.